# react update an element in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have a state like this

```
[{text: 'this is a text', time:0},{text: 'this is a another text', time:0}]
```

How can Increment the time by 1?

I am trying something like this:

```
setState((element)=>{...element,time:time+1})
```

or

```
setState(state.map((element)=>{...element,time:element.time+1}))
```

It is a simple question, I just forgot how to do it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your state should be an object
lets say your state is

```
state = {
  arr: [{ text: 'this is a text', time: 0 }, { text: 'this is a another text', time: 0 }],
};
```

then you can modify your state like this:

```
this.setState(({ arr }) => ({ arr: arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, time: item.time + 1 })) }));
```

Comment: I am using useState hook and would like it to be just an array, is there another way ?

Comment: okay this seems to work
let increm = []

       state.map((element)=>increm.push({text:th.text,time:element.time+1}))

        setState(increm)